# python iterate over list and add special key based on 'new arrival'

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have a list of items such that:

```
my_list = [ {'id':100, 'location':'A'}, {'id':100, 'location':'B'}, {'id':100, 'location':'C'}, {'id':101, 'location':'A'}, {'id':101, 'location':'G'}, {'id':100, 'location':'F'},{'id':100, 'location':'R'}]
```

If I add everything into a dictionary I will have 100:['A','B','C','F','R'] and 101:['A','G] but I want to show that 100 has 2 'rounds' such that:

```
100-round#1:['A','B','C'] #note the key is 100-round#1
101-round#1:['A','G']
...
100-round#2:['F','R']
```

What I have done so for is to get a *global dictionary* (partially desired)

```
location_dict={}
for r in my_list:
   id = r['id']
   location = r['location']
   id_locations = location_dict.get(id,[])
   id_locations.append(location)
   location_dict[id]=id_locations
```

result:

```
{100:['A','B','C','F','R'], 101:['A','G]}
```

How can I iterate over my list and create **one** dictionary where the key indicates the id (number) as well as the 'round' so I can tell that 100 had 2 rounds in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will create one ordered dictionary, where keys are strings `<id>-round#<round number>` and values are locations for the actual round:

```
from itertools import groupby, count
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict


my_list = [ {'id':100, 'location':'A'}, {'id':100, 'location':'B'}, {'id':100, 'location':'C'}, {'id':101, 'location':'A'}, {'id':101, 'location':'G'}, {'id':100, 'location':'F'},{'id':100, 'location':'R'}]

out, c = OrderedDict(), defaultdict(lambda: count(1))
for id_, g in groupby(my_list, lambda k: k['id']):
    out['{}-round#{}'.format(id_, next(c[id_]))] = [d['location'] for d in g]


for k, v in out.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Prints:

```
100-round#1 ['A', 'B', 'C']
101-round#1 ['A', 'G']
100-round#2 ['F', 'R']
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume by "round" you mean a streak of consecutive `id` values in the list. I'm going to use a `defaultdict` to avoid having to assign an empty list for new keys, but that doesn't change much of the logic relevant to you're question. Try

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [
    {'id': 100, 'location': 'A'},
    {'id': 100, 'location': 'B'},
    {'id': 100, 'location': 'C'},
    {'id': 101, 'location': 'A'},
    {'id': 101, 'location': 'G'},
    {'id': 100, 'location': 'F'},
    {'id': 100, 'location': 'R'}
]

# This keeps track of how many times we've seen each
# id, and defaults to 0.
rounds = defaultdict(int)

locations = defaultdict(list)
current_id = ''

for data in my_list:
    id = data['id']

    if id != current_id:
        # If this is true, we start a new round.
        round = rounds[id] + 1
        rounds[id] += 1
        current_id = id

    locations[f'{id}-round{round}'].append(data['location'])

print(dict(locations))
```

which yields

```
{'100-round1': ['A', 'B', 'C'], '101-round1': ['A', 'G'], '100-round2': ['F', 'R']}
```

Of course, you needn't cast `locations` to a list at the end if a `defaultdict` will work for you.